# android start activity after videoview finished

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have videoview and also an  mp4 file in my raw folder. I can successfully play my video in videoview. When the video has finished I try to start the second activity. I wrote some code but I have one problem. I checked after video finished and before second activity is starting I have one or two seconds (second activity starting after one or two seconds)

```
public  void getVideoFromHttp() {
    try {
        String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + FILE_NAME;
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(LauncherActivity.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri mVideo = Uri.parse(uri);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        videoView.setVideoURI(mVideo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoView.start();

        }
    });

    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Log.e("finished", "video finished");
            ClearStackAndStartActivity(CheckPinCodeActivity.class);
        }
    });

}


private  void ClearStackAndStartActivity(Class klass)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, klass);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);

}





final Runnable setImageRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          //start activity here
        }
    };
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(setImageRunnable);
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, 2000);
```

This is my source and I do not know what I am doing wrong. Is it possible to start second activity as soon as the video has finished? Thanks everyone.

Comment: Simple you can get seconds using your video ,So make a timer of that time(or add 2-3 seconds in that) after timer finish go to next activity.

Comment: call videoview.destroyDrawingCache() before passing Intent

Comment: do you mean Runnable ? i updated my source @JIGAR  my video durection is only two seconds

Comment: did you get an answer?